# Failing in message queue read from a file

Tags: c

I have add to some data into a text file and read out that in the 2. I have the first code to write some stuff into the text file, but in the 2. code i can't reach it. I get message error: No such file or directory. What do i miss in these? ( i have to use message queue to solve this problem)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

#define PERMS 0644
struct my_msgbuf {
   long mtype;
   char mtext[200];
};

int main(void) {
   struct my_msgbuf buf;
   int msqid;
   int len;
   key_t key;
   system("touch msgq.txt");
   
   if ((key = ftok("msgq.txt", 'B')) == -1) {
      perror("ftok");
      exit(1);
   }
   
   if ((msqid = msgget(key, PERMS | IPC_CREAT)) == -1) {
      perror("msgget");
      exit(1);
   }
   printf("message queue: ready to send messages.\n");
   printf("Enter lines of text, ^D to quit:\n");
   buf.mtype = 1; 
   
   while(fgets(buf.mtext, sizeof(buf.mtext), stdin) != NULL) {
      len = strlen(buf.mtext);
      /* remove newline at end, if it exists */
      if (buf.mtext[len-1] == '\n') buf.mtext[len-1] = '\0';
      if (msgsnd(msqid, &buf, len+1, 0) == -1) /* +1 for '\0' */
      perror("msgsnd");
   }
   strcpy(buf.mtext, "end");
   len = strlen(buf.mtext);
   if (msgsnd(msqid, &buf, len+1, 0) == -1) /* +1 for '\0' */
   perror("msgsnd");
   
   if (msgctl(msqid, IPC_RMID, NULL) == -1) {
      perror("msgctl");
      exit(1);
   }
   printf("message queue: done sending messages.\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Code to read from message que

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

#define PERMS 0644
struct my_msgbuf {
   long mtype;
   char mtext[200];
};

int main(void) {
   struct my_msgbuf buf;
   int msqid;
   int toend;
   key_t key;
   
   if ((key = ftok("msgq.txt", 'B')) == -1) {
      perror("ftok");
      exit(1);
   }
   
   if ((msqid = msgget(key, PERMS)) == -1) { 
      perror("msgget");
      exit(1);
   }
   printf("message queue: ready to receive messages.\n");
   
   for(;;) { 
      if (msgrcv(msqid, &buf, sizeof(buf.mtext), 0, 0) == -1) {
         perror("msgrcv");
         exit(1);
      }
      printf("recvd: \"%s\"\n", buf.mtext);
      toend = strcmp(buf.mtext,"end");
      if (toend == 0)
      break;
   }
   printf("message queue: done receiving messages.\n");
   system("rm msgq.txt");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the msqq.txt file? Do you need to do absolute/relative paths? It looks like it's made in the first lot of code - is that in a different directory to the 2nd lot of code?

Comment: They are all in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

Your programs work. You must first start the writer, so that the message queue is created, then start the reader, then in the writer *Enter lines of text*, which it will send to the reader, which will receive them.